# Custom Post Types 404 Issue

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, 404-error

I dont know why my custom post types render the Page not found. This is the code I am using to register custom posts.

`www.example.com/products/product1/` renders 404 where as `www.example.com/?products=product1` is perfectly fine.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type('products', array(
        'label' => __('Products'),
        'singular_label' => __('Product'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, // UI in admin panel
        '_builtin' => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
        '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d',
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array("slug" => "products"), // Permalinks format
        'supports' => array('title','author')
    ));
}
```

Comment: You need to flush your rewrite rules, one way is to visit the permalink page under settings and the other way is to call flush_rewrite_rules(). If you are shipping the above code with theme/plugin then you need to flush the rules on activation.

Answer (score 4):

Have you refreshed your rewrite rules? You can do this by resaving your permalink settings under Settings>Permalinks in the admin.

If it is a plugin or theme you are distributing you can call `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` upon activation.

Comment: Didnt knew about flush_rules();

Answer (score 4):

Yea, you need to flush the permalinks.

This helps solve the problem even further.

> ```
>     'rewrite' => array("slug" => "products"), // Permalinks format
> ```

I was getting the same problem when using

```
'rewrite' => true,
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Settings > Permalinks
2. Change your permalinks to something different to what you actually have
3. click on “Save changes”
4. Change your permalinks back to your preferred setting
5. relaod the Page.

hope that can help you

Comment: You don't need to change and re-save permalink settings, simply visiting the permalinks settings page flushes the rewrite rules without having to change anything.